# Pixi js and Fabric.js

Tags: canvas, sprite, fabricjs, pixi.js

I'm focusing now on Pixi js library. I would like to know if there is a simple way to resize and rotate sprites on the fly.

If I take that as an example,
http://www.goodboydigital.com/pixijs/examples/8/
I want to draw controls around all bunnies to enable resize and rotate with mouse and touch events (like that http://fabricjs.com/touch-events/)

Somebody knows how to achieve that?

I'm also wondering if it is useful (in term of performance) to do such canvas operations with pixi or directly with fabric.js ?

Thanks to you!

Answer (score 3):

Pixi JS is a general-purpose rendering engine, with 2d canvas and WebGL support.

It does have touch/click event support, but does not support high level features like "interactive handles" on objects. This is something that need to be built on top of PIXI.

At the time of writing, FabricJS WebGL renderer is still on the roadmap. For this reason alone you should - theoretically - get better performance with PIXI, which supports webgl rendering for a while now. Real-life difference will depend on the application of course.

Comment: Also heck out this benchmark, featuring phaser 2 / 3 - pixiJS
https://github.com/themoonrat/webgl-benchmark

Comment: New / Updated Benchmark test found here.
https://benchmarks.slaylines.io/pixi.html